# Create a drill down for a field in visual force page using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angular

Create a drill down for a field in visual force page using AngularJS

I have a visual force page using angular JS. I have include this page as a section in Contact standard page.  I need to create a drill down for one of the field to naviage a standard detail page. I understand how to do this in visual force page using outputlink. But my page is using Angular JS, 
If I do the following

```
<div  class="card"  ng-repeat="story in stories">
      <a id="link-3" ng-href = "/{{story.Id}}">{{story.title}}</a>
</div>
```

it opens the iframe in current section.

If I use do the following as I used in outputlink

```
<a id="link-3" ng-href ="window.top.location.href ='/{{story.Id}}'">{{story.title}}</a>
or
<a id="link-3" ng-click ="window.top.location.href ='/{{story.Id}}'">{{story.title}}</a>
```

neither one is working at all. I can see story.Id is resolved correctly when I inspect element in browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing need to check is cross-origin-policy. Domain, protocol and port of parent and child window/frame must match.

You can check this error in console of chrome browser.

Standard salesforce page and custom visualforce page both have different URLs.

IF it is n't the issue then try with separate function:

```
function navigate(id) {
 window.top.location.href = window.location.origin+'/'+id;
}

<a id="link-3" ng-click ="navigate('{{story.Id}}');">{{story.title}}</a>
```

---

**update:**
There is a correction to make it work:

```
 <a id="link-3" ng-click ="navigate(story.Id);">{{story.title}}</a>
```

Comment: The problem is solved,  <a id="link-3" ng-click ="navigate(story.Id);">{{story.title}}</a>